# Unable to create local ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer

Tags: c#, .net, arcgis

I'm developing with ArcGIS Runtime SDK for dotNet 10.2.6.

When I try to add an ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer with a LocalMapService to my MapView, I get and exception at the LayerLoaded event:

> exception=Failed to initialize Service_image_layer

This is the code I'm running:

```
LocalMapService localMapService = new LocalMapService(@"d:\maps\EmptyMpk.mpk");
await localMapService.StartAsync();

ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer arcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer()
                {
                    ID = "arcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
                    ServiceUri = localMapService.UrlMapService,
                };

m_MapView.Map.Layers.Add(arcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer);
```

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Would you be able to post your EmptyMpk.mpk somewhere (like Dropbox) where we could download it and give it a try? Loading a blank MPK works great for me in Runtime 10.2.6, as long as the MPK is enabled for Runtime.

Comment: I'm using the "water-distribution-network.mpk" that was provided with the desktop samples (I only renamed it). Here is a link anyway: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnviqq9y07257si/EmptyMpk.mpk?dl=0

Comment: Thanks, but water-distribution-network.mpk from https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-data/blob/master/maps/water-distribution-network.mpk and the one you linked in Dropbox are very, very different map packages. I think I see what's happening and I will post an answer for you shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtime can't use a map package or map service that contains only empty group layers and no actual data layers. Instead, use a map package that contains a feature layer with zero features in it. I have posted [an example of such a map package](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71000574/mpk_blank.mpk).

By the way, if you're loading a blank MPK so that you can add arbitrary datasets to your map, you can now add some datasets, including shapefiles and Runtime geodatabases, without going through a map package. See the [`FeatureLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference//html/T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Layers_FeatureLayer.htm) class and the [`FeatureTable`](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference//html/T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Data_FeatureTable.htm) class. `FeatureTable` has subclasses that include [`ShapefileTable`](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference//html/T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Data_ShapefileTable.htm) and [`GeodatabaseFeatureTable`](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/api-reference//html/T_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Data_GeodatabaseFeatureTable.htm).